# Unable to detect/mount zfs pool created on different machine

Tags: mount, zfs, zfsonlinux

I'm trying to mount a zfs pool created on a different machine.
To test out this scenario I have created two virtual machines in Virtualbox.
The OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1 server in both cases.
Machine1 has 5 virtual disks (one for the OS, the other four for the zpool).

```
nas1.vdi    
VirtualDisk1.vdi
VirtualDisk2.vdi
VirtualDisk3.vdi
VirtualDisk4.vdi
```

I created a pool on the `VirtualDisk*.vdi`s and everything works as expected. The output of `zpool status` on machine1:

```
  pool: bigdata
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bigdata     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
```

I created a second machine to test importing/mounting the zpool created on machine1:

```
nas2.vdi
VirtualDisk1.vdi
VirtualDisk2.vdi
VirtualDisk3.vdi
VirtualDisk4.vdi
```

where the `VirtualDisk*.vdi`s are the exact same disks from machine1 holding the zpool and `nas2.vdi` is the disk to hold the os. However no pool is detected; `zpool list` gives `no pools available`, `zpools import` gives `no pools available to import`.

The special devices `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, `/dev/sdd` and `/dev/sde/` are there.

What am I missing? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you export the pool beforehand with `zpool export`? See also this [Admin Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbchy/index.html).

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I tried `export`ing the pool but it didn't make any difference; it got unmounted from machine1 but still `no pools available` on machine2. I shut down machine1 before trying to mount the pool on machine2 btw.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same but only with one vdi file: VirtualDisk1.vdi and it worked. On the source OS (CentOS 7), I exported the pool with

```
zpool export
```

and on my destination OS (Ubuntu 16.10), I imported it with

```
zpool import -a
```

If you do not want to type this always into the command line, add this line into `/etc/crontab`

```
@reboot user sleep 30; /sbin/zpool import -a
```